# Why does Mac UK keyboard have a § key?

Tags: mac, keyboard, keyboard-layout

I got my hands on Mac with UK keyboard. I noticed that backtick key <kbd>`</kbd>  which is, in Mac US keyboard, present with the number row is replaced by a <kbd>§</kbd> key.

[image: Comparison of Mac UK and US keyboard]

The UK keyboard is on the top and the US keyboard is on the bottom.<sub>[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3jPUb.jpg)</sub>.

Why does UK keyboard needs a separate key for [Section sign <kbd>§</kbd>](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Section_sign) and [Plus-minus sign <kbd>±</kbd>](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plus-minus_sign)? I can understand the need for <kbd>£</kbd> and <kbd>€</kbd> in UK but what use do they have for <kbd>§</kbd> and <kbd>±</kbd> that is so frequent that forced manufacturers to make left shift key shorter and make space for them at top?

<sub>[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3jPUb.jpg): Image is from [this blog](http://www.paulboxley.com/blog/2010/11/mac-keyboard-differences)</sub>

Comment: I wish this wasn't closed. I'm from the UK and I've never once had a reason to use this button, so I'm really curious why it's there. There must be a reason for it, and if that reason is documented somewhere then the answer is a matter of fact, not opinion.

Comment: @Nathaniel A lot of other non-US keyboards have the § with no obvious usage. Here are few [non-US keyboards](https://github.com/tekezo/Karabiner-Elements/blob/master/usage/README.md#swapping-sectionparagraph--key-on-non-us-keyboards).

Comment: @Nathaniel Also from the support issues in [Karabiner-Elemets](https://github.com/tekezo/Karabiner-Elements/) it is obvious a lot many uses swap § key with ` accent key.

Comment: I've only recently discovered that a lot more US keyboards have the slim vertical style return key. UK Keyboards tend towards the wide horizontal return key in general (where they don't still have the really big return key of old). I hadn't realised there was a difference such that now that US _shape_ keyboards are becoming more popular in the UK, I find I often miss the US style return key and end up hitting the '\' key by accident :-\

Answer (score -1):

You gave the answer yourself in the [link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Section_sign):

> The section sign (Unicode U+00A7 § section sign, HTML §, TeX \S)
>   is a typographical character used mainly  to refer to a particular
>   **section of a document, such as a legal code**.[1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Section_sign)

Comment: This doesn't answer my question. I understand the purpose. In UK do they create documents with sections so frequently that they need a separate key for it? More than in US?